# React Native Login. How do I connect my route.js file connected to my DB to my application

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, express

Im new to React Native and I was trying to do a connection from a login screen to the backend mysql database. Now I have data and I have a route.js file which calls that data but I am at a loss how to select it in my login screen to pick out user name and password for validation. Honestly I have combed the internet for answers but none of them are really clear and the answer "Well mine works" is nice but does not help in my case.
Ill attach the 2 files below and if anyone has thoughts I would certainly be welcome to them except " well mine works"

Cheers

```
// This is a route.js file!
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const mysql =require ('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool ({
host    :'127.0.0.1',
//port  :'8012',
user    :'root',
password    :'password',
database    :'test_db'
});

const app = express ();
//Creating a get route that returns data from users table
app.get('/users' , function (req,res) {
    //Connecting to DB
    connection.getConnection (function (err, connection) {
        //Executing query
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function (error, results, fields){
            if (error) throw error;
            res.send(results)
        });
    });
});

//starting our server
app.listen (3000, () =>{
    console.log('Go to http://127.0.0.1:3000/users so you can see the data.');
});
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View, Image} from 'react-native'
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput'
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton'
import { theme } from '../core/theme'
import { emailValidator } from '../helpers/emailValidator'
import { passwordValidator } from '../helpers/passwordValidator'
import * as webBrowser from 'expo-web-browser'
import * as google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'
//web: 59045300049-q41hk0a5130f1s5cagsjkqk9jk2gniap.apps.googleusercontent.com
//ios: 59045300049-2krv3gobllv0i32vmbl0pkd3vpp45l99.apps.googleusercontent.com
//android: 59045300049-t654e5tdf62tf2qfihq47m95ib404vle.apps.googleusercontent.com

webBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = React.useState(null);
      const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
      const [request, response, promptAsync] = google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        clientId: "59045300049-q41hk0a5130f1s5cagsjkqk9jk2gniap.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        IosClientId: "59045300049-2krv3gobllv0i32vmbl0pkd3vpp45l99.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        AndroidClientId: "59045300049-t654e5tdf62tf2qfihq47m95ib404vle.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      });
      React.useEffect(() => {
        if(response?. type == "success"){
          setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
          accessToken && fetchUserInfo();
        }
      }, [response, accessToken]);
      async function fetchUserInfo(){
        let response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me", {
          headers: {
            authorization: 'Bearer ${accessToken}'}
        })
        const useInfo = await response.json();
        setUser(useInfo);
      }
  
  const [email, setEmail] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })
  const [password, setPassword] = useState({ value: '', error: '' })

  const onLoginPressed = () => {
    const emailError = emailValidator(email.value)
    const passwordError = passwordValidator(password.value)
    if (emailError || passwordError) {
      setEmail({ ...email, error: emailError })
      setPassword({ ...password, error: passwordError })
      return
    }
    navigation.reset({
      index: 0,
      routes: [{ name: 'Dashboard' }],
    })
  }
const ShowUserInfo = () => {
  if(user) {
    return(
      <view style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text style = {{fontSize: 35, fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 20}}>welcome</Text>
      <image source = {{uri: user.picture}} style = {{width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50}}/>
      <Text style= {{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{user.name}</Text>
      </view>
    )
  }
}
  return (
    <Background>
      <BackButton goBack={navigation.goBack} />
      <Logo />
      <Header>Welcome back.</Header>
      <TextInput
        label="Email"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={email.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!email.error}
        errorText={email.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      <TextInput
        label="Password"
        returnKeyType="done"
        value={password.value}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!password.error}
        errorText={password.error}
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <View style={styles.forgotPassword}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ResetPasswordScreen')}
        >
          <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot your password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Button mode="contained" onPress={onLoginPressed}>
        Login
      </Button>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {user && <ShowUserInfo />}
        {user === null &&
        <>
        <TouchableOpacity
          disabled={!request}
          onPress={() => {
            promptAsync();
          }}
          >
          <Image source={require("../assets/google-signin.png")} style={{width: 300, height: 40} }/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </>
          }
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>Don’t have an account? </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.replace('RegisterScreen')}>
          <Text style={styles.link}>Sign up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </Background>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  forgotPassword: {
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 24,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  forgot: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: theme.colors.secondary,
  },
  link: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: theme.colors.primary,
  },
})
```